# Does header initialization break RAII?

Tags: c++, raii

Consider the following C++ header:

```
#include "OtherThing.h"

class Thing
{
public:
    Thing(); //ctor

private:
    OtherThing my_var_{};
};
```

Is the private var `my_var_` still managed according to RAII, or does its lifetime exceed the scope of `Thing` in any way? I searched for a clear answer for a good while, but either formed my question poorly or didn't know how to read what was given.

Comment: In what sense do you feel that `my_var_` is *not* "wrapped in a containing class"?

Comment: Can you share what make you think that it break RAII?

Comment: How can the lifetime of a class member can possibly exceed the lifetime of it's class's instance?

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if there was a difference in lifetime in this vs. initializing the var with the constructor i.e. `Thing() : my_var_{}`

Comment: What do you mean by header initialization? `{}`? That is just a default initialization, which is executed, each time, when a `Thing` is constructed. You could very roughly compare it to default parameters of functions, which are also declared in the header, but set, when the function is called. An exception would be, if the member variable is declared as `static`. A static member variable lifetime exceeds the lifetimes of the instances.

Comment: @Sebastian "header initialization" in the sense that the variable is initialized in the .h file _and_ not explicitly attached to the ctor. I probably could have used better explanation or a better term there. Hopefully, that clears up my intent. Your comment was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the private var my_var_ still managed according to RAII, or does its lifetime exceed the scope of Thing in any way?

The data member `my_var_` is a non-static data member and is associated with a particular instance of class `Thing`. More importantly, it's lifetime can never exceed the lifetime of the associated `Thing` object.

When a given `Thing` object goes out of scope, it's data members are also destroyed. Basically, a `Thing` object includes its data members so logically when the `Thing` object is destroyed the data members will also be destroyed.

---

Also note that technically the lifetime of an object with a constructor doesn't begin until the execution of the constructor has completed. So the lifetime of the class members is slightly longer than lifetime of the containing object *as pointer out by* @[M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73131471/does-header-initialization-break-raii/73131528?noredirect=1#comment129161580_73131528)

Comment: Technically, the lifetime of an object with a constructor doesn't begin until the execution of the constructor has completed. So the lifetime of the class members is slightly longer than lifetime of the containing object.

Comment: @M.M Yes, added that at the end of my updated answer.

Comment: @AnoopRana, thank you. I just wasn't sure of the operation. I _thought_ it was better to declare the member var without the default initializer and to always initialize with the ctor, but it appears that at best, it is a preference. Thanks for the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

`OtherThing my_var_{};` is syntactic sugar to a adding `ma_var_{}` in the member initialization list of every constructor, including those generated by the compiler.

So it's the same as writing

```
Thing() : my_var_{} { } //ctor
```